# Access denied when trying to execute OpenProcess and TerminateProcess

Tags: windows, visual-c++

When I compile and execute/debug my code from Visual C++ 2010 Express using Ctrl + F5, it executes fine.

When I try to execute the exe formed after building the project, it produces an access denied error when calling `OpenProcess` and `TerminateProcess`.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

How can it be fixed?

Comment: I am running as administrator and calling the functions from a simple console application. Also when I try to call `ExitWindowsEx` it gives Access Denied error..

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that it could be caused by [UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511445.aspx). Try launching your application from elevated command prompt, or from explorer by using option "Run as administrator" in context menu.

Comment: I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: @user1232138 -- it is not enough. Make sure you select "Run as administrator" option and go through elevation prompt.

Comment: The thing is that I haven't set any password for the administrator account. So when I try to Run the program as Administrator it displays some message box saying something like "Logon failure: user account restriction". Is it possible that my compiler has a higher priviledge and so when I compile and execute the program, the program inherits the higher priviledge and gets executed satisfactorily, which doesn't happen otherwise??

Comment: @user1232138 -- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) sais that OpenProcess requires SeDebugPrivilege. If you are not running elevated, you have to call [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202(v=vs.85).aspx)